# Google ignores new robots.txt file - Won't show info in SERPs

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I'm running a Danish flight search engine. I previously setup a flawed robots.txt file that ended up removing the title tags and descriptions for most of my site.

Now I've fixed the robots.txt to this:

```
# Robots file for www.billigeflybilletter.dk
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /hoteller
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Allow: /flyforsinkelse/
```

However, the very important page `https://www.billigeflybilletter.dk/flyforsinkelse/` still shows this in the index:

[image: Google Search result for 'www.billigeflybilletter.dk/flyforsinkelse/']

Which is Danish for "nope".

What can I possibly be doing wrong here?

The robots.txt file is accesable both non HTTP and non HTTPS.

Comment: It takes some time for Google to recrawl your site. Give it some time...

Answer (score 0):

With your current robots.txt, crawling of the page in question is allowed.

You don’t need the line `Allow: /flyforsinkelse/`, as everything (which is not explicitly disallowed) is allowed to be crawled by default.

In one of the next times the Googlebot crawls something on your site, it will fetch your robots.txt, learn that it’s now allowed to crawl more than before, and will then, at some point, crawl the "new" pages (if it can find links to it). This can take minutes, hours, days, or weeks.